# AngularJS needed 2 clicks to do search action

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Im AngularJs newbie:).
But I have 3 components: controller C1 (for entering search input and clicking submit button),controller C2 (for div which will receive results from SearchService and display it) and service searchService for sending some hardocoded results.

THe idea is that after submitting search text, I have to submit it twice. With one submit click, view of ui-router is updated to partial page without results loaded. After second click the results are displayed.

Then  next searches are done on search view page, all is ok, one click gives needed data.

**How to fix it: I want to change ui-router view and get results from service with one click?**

C1 method code (started after submiting searchText)

```
$scope.searchText = function searchText(text) {
    $log.log("Method searchText with text: " + text);        
    //var parametersObject = {searchText: text, results: assetResults}

    $state.go('search');        
    $log.log("SearchInputBoxController: rootScope Broadcasting message: " + text);        

    $rootScope.$broadcast('DoSearch', text);                    

    $log.log("SearchInputBoxController finished");
};
```

C2 method: event handler for event 'DoSearch'

```
 $scope.$on('DoSearch', function (event, data) {        
    $scope.asset = searchService.search(data);
    $scope.searchText = data;            
 });
```

searchService code:

```
Application.Services.factory('SearchService', ['SearchServiceResource', '$q',
    function (SearchServiceResource, $q) {
        return {
            search : function (searchText)
            {            
                var result = [
                    {id: 'aaaaa', sn:"1234-1234-1234-1235", name:"DCU_name1", type: "DCU", tags: ["tag1", "tag2"]},
                    {id: 'aaaaa', sn:"1234-1234-1234-1235", name:"DCU_name2", type: "DCU", tags: ["tag1", "tag2"]},
                    {id: 'aaaaa', sn:"1234-1234-1234-1235", name:"NODE_name1", type: "DCU_Node", tags: ["tag1", "tag2"]}                        
                ];
                return result;
            }
        };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the clicking twice is because the first click is triggering the state change, then the broadcast occurs, and then the state change occurs. The second click, the state doesn't need to change, and the current now unchanged controller gets the broadcast. There are a couple different approaches I can think of (and I would def shy away from rootscope broadcasting):

1. in your shared service, maintain a search string variable and on your 
   controller, put  watch on that service's variable.
2. change your route/state settings to include a parameter like /search/:searchTerm and in the controller, look for the state established searchTerm variable and on the controller load see if searchTerm is provided and fire the search. [Some more info here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/3-simple-tips-for-using-ui-router)

Let me now if you need any help or more specifics on the ideas listed.

Comment: Yes. you were right. I cannot sent broadcast to not active controller. I changed this into service with set and get methods.